# Springboot Jpa join with where clause on foreign table doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities and a JpaRepository, i want to to join these two table and select only the "Trad" records that have a particular lang.

```
//Sito.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "sito")
@Data
public class Sito
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_sito", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "cod_scheda", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String codScheda;
    
    /*Some fields omitted for brevity*/

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fkIdSito" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Trad> trad = new ArrayList<>();

}


//Trad.java
@Data
@Table(name = "trad")
@Entity
public class Trad {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_trad", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "lang", length = 2)
    private String lang;

    /*Some fields omitted for brevity*/

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_sito")
    private Sito fkIdSito;

    
}

//SitoRepository.java
@Repository
public interface SitoRepository extends JpaRepository<Sito,Integer> {

@Query(
        value = "from Sito s join Trad t on s.id = t.fkIdSito where s.codScheda = :codScheda and t.lang = :lang"
    )
    Sito getSitoByCodScheda(String codScheda, String lang);

}
```

When i execute getSitoByCodScheda(...) method i get a join of Sito and Trad with all "Trads" of a "Sito", without filter by lang field.

Here is the json response:

```
{
    "id_sito": 21,
    "cod_scheda": "ABC123",
    
    /*other fields omitted*/
    
    "trad": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "lang": "it"
            /*other fields omitted*/
        },
        {
            "id": 456,
            "lang": "en"
            /*other fields omitted*/
        }
    ]
}
```

I want a response with only matched "Trad", like this:

```
{
    "id_sito": 21,
    "cod_scheda": "ABC123",
    
    /*other fields omitted*/
    
    "trad": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "lang": "it"
            /*other fields omitted*/
        }
    ]
}
```

I use Spring Boot 3.